# Maven Filtering With System Properties

Tags: java, maven

I am setting up a project using Maven filtering to "fill in the blanks" in some configuration files. However, instead of setting these up in the pom.xml as properties, I would like to make them System properties so I can create the project like this:

```
mvn install -Duser=xxxx -Dpassword=xxxx
```

In the file to be modified, I tried using `${user}` and `${password}` as the placeholders, with no luck. Is what I am trying to do even possible?

(Note: I am specifically setting up the filtering in the `<webresources>` section of the maven-war-plugin to modify a configuration file in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF).

**Update:**

Here is my `<configuration>` section of the plugin:

```
        <configuration>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/applicationContext.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
```

Here is what I am trying to modify in the targeted file:

```
<property name="user" value="${user}" />
```

I have also attempted to use `${system.user}` as the placeholder with no luck.

**Solution**

Using ${user} and ${password} worked. My problem was in the `<directory>` section of the `<resource>`:

Bad:

```
<directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
```

Good:

```
<directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
```

Comment: The command line properties look correct to me.

When setting these up using properties within the pom.xml does the filtering work as expected?

Comment: No, the filtering is not working. I've updated to show the line from /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml that I am attempting to modify.

Comment: Disregard. Changing the directory to exclude the WEB-INF seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: You got it working but just interested why would you not use profiles? Anyway you might want to share your changes as an answer to others to see also?

Comment: I didn't use profiles because that would have required me to create a new profile section for each user.